# Dell UPS Management Software and shutting down multiple servers

Tags: windows-server-2008

Does the Dell UPS Management Software allow multiple servers shutdown from the machine connected to the UPS via USB?

If not, how can we shutdown both the machines when only one is connected to the UPS via USB?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dell sells APC, which is what I assume you have. The APC software allows you to run scripts on power events. Just run `shutdown /m \\otherComputers /s /t x` where x is a number of seconds. I usually do 30 to allow enough time for a graceful closing of most services. If you have a big process on the target like Exchange, adjust accordingly.

Comment: Dell also sells rebranded Eaton UPS'. See http://dellups.com/

Answer (score 2):

Catch the shutdown event and then use `shutdown.exe` to remotely shutdown any PC/Server in your network.

Answer (score 1):

Goto dellups.com and follow the Software and Technical Documentation link.
http://dellups.com/soft-tech-doc.asp
Enter the model of Dell ups and download the latest Dell UPS Management software.
NOTE: Ignore the Firmware download link as it gives some blurb about it being "not available".  That is wrong.  The Software download has them both. The management software download and the UPS firmware download propagate as the same download for some confusing reason. One version will be an updated management software, and another version release will be a UPS firmware update.  Look at the Download Type and it will say Application or Firmware. So you do not know which the link will give at any specific day. 
Alternately goto dell.com and use their Search for "UPS Firmware".
Another option for direct download is http://ftp.us.dell.com/firmware/  and examine the Dell_Multi-Device_* files which are the various versions of management software and firmware updates.
Current most updated firmware is DELL_MULTI-DEVICE_A03-00_R315767.exe
Current most updated software is DELL_MULTI-DEVICE_A00_R318771.exe

The latest UPS Management software release splits the into a Dell Multi-UPS Management Console (MUMC) and a Dell UPS Local Node Manager (ULNM). MUMC is for the Enterprise-level management of all ULNM and NMC nodes you have at all your sites.  With ULNM you can set up one local node (i.e. server) called the "Shutdown Controller" that collects the UPS alerts and directs all other machines how/when to shut down. Or you can set the ULNM apps on each system to listen to their respective UPS (via NMC network card in the UPS) on their own and control their own shutdown. NOTE - a Shutdown Controller must be the last system to shutdown and can only obtain alerts via USB connection to the UPS. All servers to be controlled must host the ULNM app.

Note - You are not supposed to have ANY other variety of Dell Management Console software installed as they use the same network ports for communications apparently.

Read the extensive PDF documentation for interaction with virtuals hosts and the various design scenarios they cover.

FYI - if you receive an Eaton PAC error message when trying to install the applications, uninstall the Firmware Update application and then go into the Windows registry and delete the Dell UPS Upgrade Software and Eaton keys from HKLM/Software/.  That is what I had to do once.

Comment: I set this up today. The new software is definitely a lot easier to install and understand. With a single MUMC install on my vCenter Server I'm able to shut down all ESXi hosts, and the vCenter server itself. The VMware integration is all I need, but physical hosts can be simply added by installing ULNM. Right now, all my hosts start shutting down simultaneously, so I'm still a bit confused about configuring the timings, for example shutting down the vCenter Server last.

Comment: As a follow-up to my previous comment, my MUMC installation does *not* gracefully shutdown my VM's. It detects the hosts via the vCenter integration but on the 'battery low' event it then simply powers off the hosts! I do have the VM shutdown settings configured in each ESXi host, so I would expect a graceful shutdown, and I have 'Remote Shutdown' enabled on each node in MUMC. Any tips?